# Derivation of convergence criterion for $\prod(1+|a_n|)$ from criterion for $\prod(1+a_n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

If we know the following convergence criteria for infinite products is correct

$$\boxed{\sum a_{n}\text{ converges }\Leftrightarrow\prod\left(1+a_{n}\right)\text{ converges, for real }a_{n}>0}$$

Then it immediately follows that

$$\boxed{\sum|a_{n}|\text{ converges }\Leftrightarrow\prod(1+|a_{n}|)\text{ converges}}$$

because $|a_n|>0$, even for complex $a_n$ as required by the first criteria.

**Question: This this logic correct?** I am asking because I have seen source which derive the first criterion ([eg](https://fromprimestoriemann.blogspot.com/2021/07/infinite-products-revisited.html)), and then derive the second in a complicated way. What am I missing?

Comment: Well, if $a>0$ then $|a|=a$

Comment: Kind of, so long as your original sequence $\alpha$ contains no $0$ terms.  Essentially, you you have performed universal instantiation on the original claim with the sequence $\beta: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R_{>0 } := \left| \alpha\right|$ for any given sequence $\alpha: \mathbb N \to \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$.

If your sequence does contain $0$-terms then removing them does not change the convergence of either series or product, so then you reduce to the prior case and then what you whish to prove holds.

Comment: hi @user2628206 thanks, this is helpful. In this case the factors in the product can't be 0 because $a_n>0$ is asserted. Have I misunderstood your point about zeros?

Comment: On my reading you only asserted that $\forall n \in \mathbb N_: \alpha_n > 0$ for the statement in the first box. The claim $\forall n \in \mathbb N_: \alpha_n > 0$ doesn't makes sense in the complex case as $\mathbb C$ is not ordered.  However if you implicitly had that $\alpha: \mathbb N \to \mathbb C$  contains no nonzero terms then my discussion about $0$-terms is superfluous. Note It's  true that $\left|\alpha_n\right| > 0$ for $\alpha_n \in \mathbb C$ if and only if $\alpha_n \neq 0$. You didn't include any commentary about this case nor did you rule it out explicitly so I mentioned it.

Comment: i.e. just doing universal instantiation on the first statement will get you the claim $\boxed{\sum|a_{n}|\text{ converges }\Leftrightarrow\prod(1+|a_{n}|)\text{ converges} \text{ for real } \left|\alpha_n\right| > 0}$. This statement is strictly weaker than your second statement, as means one cannot deduce the claim for sequence $\alpha: \mathbb N \to \mathbb C$ where there is an $n$ such that $\alpha_n = 0$. However as I argued prior as $0$ terms do not change the values of either the left or the right hand side, nor the convergence, so it is a quick argument to remove this extra hypothesis.

Comment: You could call me out and say that I am being pernickety, and I wouldn't say you were incorrect. My argument though  is that your second claim isn't immediate as you have to do a very small amount of reasoning. However your claim is spot on. Hope this helps

Comment: hi @user2628206 - I think I finally understand - my apologies, I'm not trained as a mathematician. You're right, the second statement is missing a condition $|a_n|>0$ which is equivalent to $a_n\neq0$ for complex $a_n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\prod (1+a_n)$ converges iff $ \sum a_n$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426670/prod-1a-n-converges-iff-sum-a-n-converges)